# Create slope full width css3

Tags: html, css, svg, diagonal

I'm trying to create a slope/diagonal with SVG (first time, other alternatives accepted) and im having a lot of issues with it. My goal is:

- Create a full width slope (ready for responsive)
- I want to have the slope on top of a div section and other on bottom
- if there is an alternative, to .svg, i would be glad to hear it

This is how the slopes, should look like:

- initial webdesign
  [image]
- [design mockup](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/24548844/Untitled_Page%20%281%29.png)
- [how the slope has to be](http://prntscr.com/3uxbj5)

I don't want to use an `.png`, then it will blur and I want as perfect as possible.

[Here's my test fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/8Lbj7/)

The yellow part, should be the one with slope, on bottom or top of the div/svg.

Any help?

**HTML**

```
<div>
       <svg width="100%" height="200">
       <rect xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" transform="rotate(-3.39492 500.731 6.21164)" stroke-opacity="0" id="svg_2" height="55" width="100%" y="-1" x="-3" stroke="#000000" fill="#f0dc10"/>
       </svg>
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
#svg_2{
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 50px;
}
```

Comment: does it have to be svg? could you tilt a div or pseudoelement?

Comment: Could be something else, as it has full width and it is a slope.

Comment: You could do something in css then like this: http://jsfiddle.net/jme11/D9M2L/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're open to a css solution you could do something like this:

Demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/jme11/D9M2L/

**CSS**

```
body {
    background-color: #000;
    margin: 0px;
}
p {
    color: white;
}
section {
    position: relative;
    background: blue;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
}
section:before {
    position: absolute;
    content:'';
}
section.diagonal {
    background: blue;
}
footer {
    position: relative;
    background: black;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
}
footer:before {
    position: absolute;
    content:'';
}
footer.diagonal {
    background: black;
}
.diagonal {
    z-index: 1;
    padding: 3em;
}
.diagonal:before {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-3deg);
    transform: rotate(-3deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 3% 0;
    transform-origin: 3% 0;
    top: 0;
    left: -25%;
    z-index: -1;
    width: 150%;
    height: 75%;
    background: inherit;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<header>
    <p>Header</p>
</header>
<section class="diagonal">
    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
</section>
<footer class="diagonal">
    <p>Footer</p>    
</footer>
```

If you want support for IE9 add the ms- prefix for the transform: http://caniuse.com/#search=transform

Comment: Thank you, it helped me a lot :)